# Issue with spark csv reading on spark 1.6.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hitting with the error when i am trying to read the CSV file .I m using spark 1.6.1 here is my code

```
 val reftable_df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") 
    .option("inferSchema", "true") 
    .load("/home/hadoop1/Reference_Currencyctoff.csv")
    reftable_df.show()

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.package$.<init>(package.scala:27)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.inferSchema(CsvRelation.scala:218)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.<init>(CsvRelation.scala:72)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:157)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
        at scb.HBaseBroadcast$.main(HBaseBroadcast.scala:138)
        at scb.HBaseBroadcast.main(HBaseBroadcast.scala)
```

Note : Already i tired with following CSV dependencies

Spark Csv » 1.3.0
Spark Csv » 1.3.1
Spark Csv » 1.4.0 
Spark Csv » 1.5.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced same issue

```
--jars /path/to/spark-csv.jar,/path/to/commons-csv.jar
```

solved the issue.

commons-csv.jar has this class

you can see the class using `jar -tvf commons-csv.jar | grep CSVFormat`

Answer (score 0):

try this while starting spark shell

```
bin/spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0
```

include this package